# Submitting form fails with form.submit, sendkeys,click and fire.event

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I have to simulate pressing enter on an HTML page input textbox.

The way it works is enter search criteria then press enter to search for the record via the default search criteria, or you can use the selector to choose a different type of search. You click on the drop down then click on the selection and the search is performed!

```
<input class="inp" type=text **name="inputboxvalue"** value="?"
                                   size="12" maxlength="12" tabindex=1 style="background-color:#EFFAE5;">
                            
                                <**select name="GOTO"** size="1" onChange="gotoMenu(this);" style="font-size:11px;">
                                    <option>GOTO ....
```

I tried several ways. I can input the proper search values into the textbox
field and that's it.

One other problem is that this will be done invisibly so there may be a focus problem, but for now it is visible.

I tried sendkeys with the form front and visible with no success.

```vb
oBrowser.Document.Forms(0).all("inputboxvalue").Value = "1234567"

sendkeys "{RETURN}"  
'sendkeys "{ENTER}"
'oBrowser.Document.Forms(0).all("getrecordid").submit (Tried this as well)
```

This is the form part that shows it is by post, so the submit is hidden.

```
 <form name="sam_0000004" method="post" action="/samcz1TSUQlM2FBTk9OJTNhYDEA" accept-charset="windows-1251, US-ASCII" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="~OkCode" value="">
```

I tried putting form name ("sam_0000004") instead of (0) in the submit code.

Because the internet explorer will be behind sendkeys is not an option so I'd have to do it with sendinput, but have never tried coding for it and examples I've seen seem complex.

Answer (score 0):

After trying umteen combinations , I finally got it to work this way!

```
Dim eFRM, eFRM2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
      Set eFRM2 = myBrowser.Document.getElementById("GOTO")

    eFRM2.FireEvent ("OnChange")
```

Looks like I needed to be more specific with the FireEvent

Pete